# Changing character variable to factor

Tags: r, recode

I've got an R script that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, and I've identified the problem as being something to do with my character -> factor conversion before I merge two datasets together.

I have a list of subjects that are coded as '1', '2', '3', etc. in data1 and '01', '02', '03', etc. in data2, and I want to recode participant numbers in data1 to match data2. I first try to convert data1$subj to a factor, and then recode the data using fct_recode in forcats. Neither of the following two options work:

```
library(forcats)
data1$subj <- as.factor(data1$subj)

data1 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(subj = fct_recode(subj,
                             "01" = "1",
                             "02" = "2",
                             "03" = "3"))
```

or

```
data1 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(subj = factor(subj),
  subj = fct_recode(subj,
                       "01" = "1",
                       "02" = "2",
                       "03" = "3"))
```

When I go back to data1 to check subj, it remains as a character variable throughout, and so the data won't recode.

As I said above, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't! I've clearly missed some nuance in my code. Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: If you only have subjects 1,2,3, you can use the base R direct assignment like `levels(data1$subj) <- 1:3` assuming that they are ordered properly. An alternative (that strips off the leading 0) is `levels(temp) <- gsub("^0", "", levels(temp))`. The second respects order and is probably safer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the library `forcats`. However I would try

```
levels(data1$subj)[levels(data1$subj)=="01"] <- "1"
[etc.]
```

OR:

```
library(plyr) 
revalue(data1$subj , c("01"="1", "02"="2","03"="3"))
```

Comment: glad it helps. you can always choose the above as the best answer :)